# What does this awk command do?

Tags: awk

What does this awk command do?

```
awk 'NR > 1 {for(x=1;x<=NF;x++) if(x == 1 || (x >= 4 && x % 2 == 0)) 
printf "%s", $x (x == NF || x == (NF-1) ? "\n":"\t")}' depth.txt 
> depth_concoct.txt
```

I think
`NR > 1` means it starts from second line,
`for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)` means for every fields,
`if(x == 1 || (x >= 4 && x % 2 == 0))` means if `x` equals `1` or (I don' understand the codes from this part and so on)
and I know that the input file for awk is `depth.txt` and the output of awk will be saved to `depth_concoct.txt`.
What does the codes in the middle mean?

Comment: It outputs every 1st, 4th and every even-numbered field after the 4th tab-separated starting from the second record from file `depth.txt` and writes it to `depth_concoct.txt`.

Comment: Thank you @James, now I know that if(x == 1 || (x >= 4 && x % 2 == 0)) means that x=1 or x is divisible by 2 from column 4. Can you tell me what $x (x == NF || x == (NF-1) ? "\n":"\t")} means? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '
NR > 1 {                                     # starting from the second record
    for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)                       # iterate every field 
        if(x == 1 || (x >= 4 && x % 2 == 0)) # for 1st, 4th and every even-numbered field after 4th
            printf "%s",                     # print the field and after it 
                $x (x == NF || x == (NF-1) ? "\n":"\t")  # a tab or a newline if its the last field
}' depth.txt > depth_concoct.txt
```

`(x == NF || x == (NF-1) ? "\n":"\t")` is called conditional operator, in this context it's basically streamlined version of:

```
if( x == NF || x == (NF-1) )  # if this is the last field to be printed
    printf "\n"               # finish the record with a newline
else                          # else
    printf "\t"`              # print a tab after the field
```

Answer (score 1):

you can rewrite it as below, which should be trivial to read.

```
$ awk `NR>1 {printf "%s", $1;  
             for(x=4;x<=NF;x+=2) printf "\t%s", $x;
             print ""}' inputfile > outputfile
```

the complexity of the code is sometimes just an implementation detail.

prints first and every second field starting from the 4th.

Assume your file has 8 fields, this is equivalent to

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR>1{print $1,$4,$6,$8}' inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: Thank you for your example!  I also will post my code so it is more readable from now on. Thank you very much!